# CLI PHP script gives "ERROR: Error accessing the registry."

Tags: windows-10, php

I have a CLI PHP script I made which does this:

```
<?php shell_exec('reg import OneDrive.reg');
```

(OneDrive.reg disables OneDrive cancer.)

With zero changes from yesterday, it suddenly gives:

```
ERROR: Error accessing the registry.
```

Yesterday and many days before, it instead said something like:

```
The command finished successfully.
```

What? How is this even possible? I have made ZERO changes and it just keeps breaking without me doing anything.

If I tediously go through the million steps required to manually open cmd.exe "as administrator", and then type "cd" and copy and paste the dir to the relevant dir (it doesn't work to drag and drop it for some absurd reason...) and then type "php test.php", it executes with *zero output*. No error message. No success message.

I really don't know what to make of this, but it truly disturbs me that even things that work at first suddenly stop working for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why it was working and now does now, but it sounds like the account running PHP doesn't have sufficient privileges.

I don't know which OS, etc you are using, and I only have a suggestion for Windows running PHP on IIS. In this case I would try:

1) Choose or Set up a new user with admin privileges.
2) Set the Identity on the Application Pool running your website to be "Custom Account" and supply the credentials for your Administrator user.
3) Refresh the Application Pool

That solved it for me, but it may not be ideal to have such a privileged user powering your PHP.